# Merge test coverage from multiple go modules

Tags: go

We have a git repository that has two go modules because we want to import only the submodule in other projects

Example:

```
go.mod
go.sum
cmd/api
  main.go
internal/foo
  foo.go
internal/bar
  bar.go
pkg/middleware
  go.mod        <- another module
  go.sum
  middleware.go
```

For both modules, we can calculate the coverage correctly but have no way to merge both reports, which we would like to have calculated in CI.

We've tried the approach that we use to merge code from different suites (unit, integration, e2e)

```
echo 'mode: atomic' > coverage.cov
tail -q -n +2 coverage.*.suite >> coverage.cov
go tool cover -html=coverage.cov
```

After we merge all the files, `coverage.cov` contains all the line hits for both modules, but `go tool cover` only builds the report for the main module, and ignores the submodule lines.

Is there a way to merge the coverage from multiple go modules?

Comment: A module is a set of packages with the same lifecycle. Combining coverage from different modules is not a sensible metric.

Comment: "because we want to import only the submodule in other projects" you don't import modules at all. Modules are used only for dependency management. You import packages. The only reason to make them separate modules is if they are versioned completely independently.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question today. I am sharing a work around for this problem.

One way to solve this problem is to use `gocov` tool

`go install github.com/axw/gocov/gocov@latest`

`go install github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml@latest`

go to the module directory and generate the coverage json using gocov tool

`cd pkg/middleware`

then generate coverage json file

`gocov test ./... > coverage_middleware.json`

`cd -`

generate the coverage json for main module using the gocov

`gocov test ./... > coverage_main.json`

Now use jq to merge these json and gocov-xml to generate the xml

`jq -n '{ Packages: [ inputs.Packages ] | add }' pkg/middleware/coverage_middleware.json coverage_main.json | gocov-xml > coverage.xml`

Hope it will help some one. If anyone has better solution, please share.